# Convert Eviews date format to python date

Tags: python, date

I have my vector dates in this format 2022M8,2022M09, etc... (eviews format). How do i read this type of string dates in python?

I wish convert this dates in this 20220801 format.

Thanks in advance!!

I have tried this:

```
date_time_str = '1973M10'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y M /%m')


print ("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small typo ?
this works just fine:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '1973M10'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%YM%m')
print ("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

gives:

```
The type of the date is now <class 'datetime.datetime'>
The date is 1973-10-01 00:00:00
```

From there, read the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) to output in your desired format.